# php/mysql CI when ever I insert data into child table it didnot store the id of parent table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am using Codeignator framework, creating a category of country and city.

### my tables

```
CREATE TABLE country(
coun_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREAMENT,
coun_name varchar(60),
child_id int(11),
PRIMARY KEY(coun_id)
);

CREATE TABLE city(
city_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREAMENT,
city_name varchar(11),
coun_id int(11),
PRIMARY KEY(city_id),
FOREIGN KEY(coun_id) REFERENCE country(coun_id)
);
```

### Model

```
$query = $this->db->where(['coun_name'=>$cat_country])->get('country');
if ( $query->num_rows() == 1){
    $data_city = array('city_name' =>$cat_city);
    $this->db->insert('city',$data_city);
}else{
    $data_con = array('coun_name'=>$cat_country);
    $this->db->insert('country',$data_con);
    $data_city = array('city_name' =>$cat_city);            
    $this->db->insert('city',$data_city);
}
```

**output**
suppose country is not found.

### country table

```
coun_id || coun_name ||child_id ==> 
1       || Pakistan  || 0
```

### city table

```
city_id || city_name ||coun_id ==>
1       || Karachi   || 0
```

**how can I get coun_id of the country table in city table?**

Comment: $this->db->insert('country',$data_con); after this stmt use last insert statement which will give you the last insert country is & then insert this country id in city table

Comment: use  $this->db->insert_id(); to get last insert id in codeignator. if we use this after insert query we will get that inserted id .

Comment: at the time of selection country in the view you have to insert coun_id in the city table

Comment: would last inserted id give me accurate country? which I need

Comment: @pAsh yes I want exactly what you are saying can you code for me?
how can I send the id of country in city table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code :

```
$query = $this->db->where(['coun_name'=>$cat_country])->get('country');
    if ( $query->num_rows() == 1){
        //get country data
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        $coun_id = $data['coun_id']; //get country id 
        $data_city = array('city_name' =>$cat_city,'coun_id'=>$coun_id);
        $this->db->insert('city',$data_city);
    }else{
        $data_con = array('coun_name'=>$cat_country);
        $this->db->insert('country',$data_con);
        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        $data_city = array('city_name' =>$cat_city,'coun_id'=>$insert_id);  
        $this->db->insert('city',$data_city);
    }
```

Comment: when ever I add another city of same country it gives undefine index coun_id.. why?

Comment: @GhufranKhalil for same country it goes into your 1st 'if' condition.. where you will get available country data... (in above code syntax may be wrong to get data but logically it is correct) check syntax